# PHP Checking lowest variables in IF Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to find the lowest variables,

I have the following code as you can see I have formatted the code so I could check and work on it, but cant seem to get my head round it.

```
if($plusadd < $takeaway || $plusadd == $takeaway
   &&
   $plusadd < $msum || $plusadd == $msum 
   &&
   $plusadd < $dsum || $plusadd == $dsum
  )
  {
      echo "work on plus sums";
  }
```

I was going to use the same code for each variable so it would echo the lowest or even lowest ie (1st, 2nd, 2nd, 4th)

The variables used above are values of data

```
|  plusadd  |  takeaway  |  dsum  |  msum  |
|    2      |     1      |    2   |    6   |
```

so i am tring to find the lowest value then echo something

at the moment takeaway is the lowest so this would echo a statement but if dsum was the same it would too echo a statement.

Comment: Add and extra set of brackets around each line, eg `if(($plusadd < $takeaway || $plusadd == $takeaway)&&(..)&&(..)`

Comment: Can you review your question to make it clearer? Can you show an example with actual values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to gather them inside an array (the variables), and then use [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) to get the lowest value.

Example:

```
$lowest = min(array($plusadd, $takeaway, $msum));
```

Comment: what would happen if two the varibles are of the same value?

Answer (score 1):

use the sort($array) function to sort an array of element from the smallest to the bigest
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sort.php